# Taylor expansions of $\text{atan}(\tan(x))$ and $\text{asin}(\sin(x))$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Do they actually exist? At least in a form that doesn't degenerate into a mantissa function or into repeated ranges of f(x)=x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taylor expansion is always analytic within the radius of convergence and hence doesn't allow discontinuities in the limit function or its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

In a neighborhood of $0$, $\arctan(\tan(x))=\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$. Therefore, the Taylor series for each function at $0$ is $x$.

Except at points where the derivative vanishes or blows up, $\arctan(\tan(x))=j\pi+x$ and $\arcsin(\sin(x))=k\pi+(-1)^kx$ for some $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, these will be the Taylor series at those points.

There won't be any convergence problems since the Taylor series, where it exists, will always be first degree polynomial.